# passing arguments to JavaScript function inside input field vs. from inside function

Tags: javascript, html, function, argument-passing

What are the pros/cons between the following two ways of passing/setting variables?

`<input type="password" name="pw1" id="pw1" onkeyup="return passwordCheck(document.getElementById('pw1'), document.getElementById('pw2'))"/`

`function passwordCheck(first, second){...`

OR

`<input type="password" name="pw1" id="pw1" onkeyup="return passwordCheck()"/`

```
function passwordCheck(){
var first = document.getElementById('pw1')
var second = document.getElementById('pw2')...
```

Comment: In the first one you can call the function with any two values, whereas the second one you will always check only the values of the elements inside of the function. Other than that I cannot think of any pro/con.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes your html markup easier to read (and your js code).  It (moreso) decouples your code from your markup.  An even better approach would be to bind an event listener to the input by targeting the id. That way you have NO js in your markup.

edit to respond to comment: I was referring to the 2nd example (calling a function) being better, but overall it's better to do event binding.  There are various methods to do it, here is an example:

```
<input type="password" name="pw1" id="pw1"/>

// ...

document.getElementByID('pw1').onkeyup = function() { 
  // do stuff
}
```